# JSON invalid character error

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, json

when json is sent from the VB.net it sends it as text. When I inspect the data parameter in the ajax success I see `data = [{'PageInformation':'test'}]`

But in the following I get  invalid character error  --WHY?

```
var dataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes: `data = [{"PageInformation":"test"}]`